# Formatting of Date class in java

Tags: java, android, string, date, simpledateformat

In android, i retrieved the value of date(EditText) in 1st line and then converted string date into dd-mm-yyyy date format.

But exception is thrown at 3rd line.
I am converting this because i want to save date in database.

plz explain

```
String d = dateView.getText().toString();
Date date;
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
      try {

        date= df.parse(d);
     } 
    catch (ParseException e) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Date format is wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

this method is called when save button is clicked:

```
public void save(View view)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "in save method",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    EditText nameView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText dateView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
    EditText amountView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);
    String name = nameView.getText().toString();
     String d = dateView.getText().toString();

    try {
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    } catch (Exception e1) {

        Toast.makeText(this, e1+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
          try {

        date= df.parse(d);
     } 
    catch (ParseException e) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Date format is wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try{
        amt = Integer.parseInt(amountView.getText().toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(this, e+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    long l = helper.insert(name,date,amt);
    Toast.makeText(this, l+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

}
```

Comment: Show the error to us.

Comment: app just shuts down force fully....@Remees M Syde

Comment: What is the value of `dateView.getText().toString()`? Also might be a good idea to replace `Toast.makeText...` with some simple logging since it might be the case that the `Toast..` call is failing as well.

Comment: date is in the format - dd-mm-yyyy in the string d. --@npinti

Comment: errors are:    FATAL exception:main    and   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity   @RemeesMSyde

Comment: In the code added in your last edit you never declared the Date object `date`

Comment: that date object and df are declared as instance variable-@Woodsy

Answer (score 1):

Try instantiating the Date object

```
Date date = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible exceptions to be thrown by your code with regard to date parsing .
  **1. ParseException** if your input does match with your date format (i.e. dd-MM-yyyy).
**2. NullPointerException** if your input is null i.e. `d`